# How to delete permanently a X number of rows from a .CSV file in RStudio

Tags: r, csv, rstudio

I'm having some dificulties trying to delete a certain number of rows from a .CSV file that i already uploaded into the RStudio Workspace.

I did try to use the following command:

(TableName <- TableName[c(-ROW1,-ROW2)]);

.... But nothing seems to happen. The total number of rows are still the same, after i execute that command.

I hope that my question is clear enough.

Best regards,
Luís

Comment: You forgot to put a comma. Example: `mtcars <- mtcars[c(-1, -2), ]` or `mtcars <- mtcars[-c(1,2), ]`. Your code will remove columns instead of rows.

Comment: A little mistake that makes a huge difference, Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone have the same question, here is the answear:

My sintax was:

(TableName <- TableName[c(-ROW1,-ROW2)]);

The correct syntax is:

(TableName <- TableName[c(-ROW1,-ROW2),]);

Credits to @ahly